Why the different default parameters for scikit-learn gradient boosting classifiers? (GradientBoostingClassifier and HistGradientBoostingClassifier)
Why do gradient boosting classifiers (GradientBoostingClassifier) and histogram-based gradient boosting classifiers (HistGradientBoostingClassifier) have significantly different default hyperparameter values in scikit-learn, and how should one best reconcile those differences?
Given these two premises:

The scikit-learn design principles include sensible defaults for their objects
To the best of my understanding, histogram-based gradient boosting classifiers are conceptually nearly identical to ordinary gradient boosting classifiers, except that the inputs are binned

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around why the default hyperparameters are different if the above premises are correct. Here are the biggest differences between the two classifiers (hereafter, referred to as Gradient and HistGradient):



Parameter
Gradient
HistGradient




max_depth
3
None


min_samples_leaf
1
20


max_leaf_nodes
None
31


n_iter_no_change
None
10



The different max_depth defaults are a dramatic change; max_depth=3 for the Gradient classifier is an incredibly shallow tree, whereas max_depth=None doesn't constrain tree depth at all. On the other hand, the min_samples_leaf and max_leaf_nodes constraints on the HistGradient classifier seem arbitrary, and might make less sense than constraining the tree depth, depending on the data. The different n_iter_no_change defaults mean that HistGradient classifiers use early stopping by default whereas Gradient classifiers do not.
What should I make of these different defaults? Are there theoretical or algorithmic reasons to limit max_depth vs. min_samples_leaf vs. max_leaf_nodes in gradient boosting methods?
Of course I should explore the best hyperparameter values for my data, but the differences seem to violate the "sensible defaults" design principle, while also making a hyperparameter search start in dramatically different places.
